# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop while I provide an unique key

Tags: reactjs

I have provided a unique key ( blog._id)  in the home.js file but still its giving me this error. I am using  useContext hook with useReducer.

Exact warning :

> react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list
> should have a unique "key" prop.
>
> Check the render method of `Home`. See
> https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
> at Blogdetails (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:129:5)

home.js

```
     import{useEffect} from 'react'
import Blogdetails from '../components/blogdetails'
import Form from '../components/form'
import { useBlogContext } from '../hooks/useblog'


 const  Home=()=> {

 const {blogs, dispatch} =useBlogContext()

  useEffect(()=>{
    const  fetchBlogs= async()=>{

      const blogPost= await fetch('/api/workouts')
      const res=await  blogPost.json()

      if(blogPost.ok){
        dispatch({type:'CREATE_BLOG', payload:res})
      }

    }

    fetchBlogs()
      
// eslint-disable-next-line 
  },[])

return (
    <div className="home">
    
    <div className="worksouts">

      {blogs && blogs.map((blog)=>(
          <Blogdetails key={blog._id} blog={blog}/>
      ))}
    </div>
      <Form/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

blogdetails.js

```
    const Blogdetails = ({blog}) => {
  return (
    <div className="workout-details">
        <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
        <h5>{blog.des}</h5>
        


    </div>
  )
}

export default Blogdetails
```

form.js

```
    import { useState } from "react"
import { useBlogContext } from '../hooks/useblog'

const Form = () => {

const{dispatch} = useBlogContext()
const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
const [des, setDes] = useState('')
const [error, setError] = useState(null)

const handle= async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()

    const blogs= {title,des}

    const res = await fetch('/api/workouts',{
        method:'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify(blogs),
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
   })
   const jon= await res.json()

   if(!res.ok){
        setError(jon.error)
   }
   if(res.ok){
    setTitle('')
    setDes('')
    setError(null)
    console.log('new blog added',jon)
    dispatch({type:'CREATE_BLOG', payload:jon})
   }

   
}


  return (


    <form onSubmit={handle}>

    <input type="text" value={title}  onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}  placeholder="title" />
    <input type="text" value={des}  onChange={(e) => setDes(e.target.value)} placeholder="description" />
    <button>add</button>

    {error && <div className="error">{error}</div>}


    </form>
   
  )
}

export default Form
```

useblog.js

```
     import{blogContext} from "../context/blogcontext"
import { useContext } from "react"

export const useBlogContext=()=>{
    const context = useContext(blogContext)

    if(!context){
        throw Error('exception occured in the context')
    }

    return context
}
```

index.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BlogContextprovider } from './context/blogcontext';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
 
    <React.StrictMode>

      <BlogContextprovider>
      <App />
      </BlogContextprovider>
    
  </React.StrictMode>
    
  
  
);
```

blogcontext.js

```
 import { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export const blogContext = createContext();

export const BlogReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_ALL_BLOGS':
      return {
        blogs: action.payload,
      };
    case 'CREATE_BLOG':
      return {
        blogs: [action.payload, ...state.blogs],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const BlogContextprovider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(BlogReducer, {
    blogs: [],
  });

  return (
    <blogContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </blogContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(blogs)`  in home.js and add the result to the question? Maybe you have non-unique _id in blogs.

Comment: i am fetching data from mongodb while i was using state everything was working fine but  useReducer creating the problem

Comment: i have add the result plz check

Comment: Can you try in Home.js dispatch GET_ALL_BLOGS instead of CREATE_BLOG?

Comment: man it works....tnx a lot

Comment: ok good, you can close the question, as it may be considered typo

Comment: system not letting me delete it